# Request origin cannot be verified - Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

[image]I'm developing an app for Shopify. Currently under development stage. Until now, I have successfully managed to authorise the app and then redirect it back to admin page using the Embedded App SDK. However, when I return to the admin page, it gives me an error saying `Request origin cannot be verified`.

The console shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)`
The URL in the console is something like this `https://myshop.myshopify.com/admin/apps/dfdjf4343343434343434bfdf/shopify/shopify/callback?code=ffdfdffd&hmac=fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdfdf&shop=myshop.myshopify.com&state=151193864548800&timestamp=1511938648`

The `fdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfddfdfdfdfdf` are just random characters that I've replaced instead of a hash. FYI - I've removed the app name and user profile name and avatar from the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because, you are unable to match state, that is set in cookie, while responding with redirect url

```js
const ShopifyToken = require('shopify-token')

const forwardingAddress = process.env.HOST

const shopifyToken = new ShopifyToken({
  sharedSecret: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  redirectUri: forwardingAddress + '/shopify/callback',
  apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY
})


const shopify = {
  // use this for authentication
  auth: (req, res, next) => {
    const shop = req.query.shop
    if (!shop) {
      return res.status(400).send('Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request')
    }
    const shopRegex = /^([\w-]+)\.myshopify\.com/i
    const shopName = shopRegex.exec(shop)[1]
    const state = shopifyToken.generateNonce()
    const url = shopifyToken.generateAuthUrl(shopName, scopes, state)
    res.cookie('state', state)
    res.redirect(url)
  },

  // use this as your callback function
  authCallback: async (req, res) => {
    const { shop, hmac, code, state } = req.query
    const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state
    if (state !== stateCookie) {
    // you are unable to set proper state ("nonce") in this case, thus you are getting this error
      return res.status(403).send('Request origin cannot be verified')
    }
    if (!shop || !hmac || !code) {
      res.status(400).send('Required parameters missing')
    }
    let hmacVerified = shopifyToken.verifyHmac(req.query)
    console.log(`verifying -> ${hmacVerified}`)
    // DONE: Validate request is from Shopify
    if (!hmacVerified) {
      return res.status(400).send('HMAC validation failed')
    }
    const accessToken = await shopifyToken.getAccessToken(shop, code)
    const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/shop.json'
    const shopRequestHeaders = {
      'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken
    }
    try {
      const shopResponse = await request.get(shopRequestUrl, { headers: shopRequestHeaders })
      res.status(200).end(shopResponse)
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as this is, also make sure that the protocol matches from what you typed in to start the app install.

If you accidentally use `http` for `http://you.ngrok.io/` but your callback redirects to `https` (i.e. `https://you.ngrok.io/auth/callback`), the OAuth handshake will fail.

Answer (score -2):

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config();
const cookie = require('cookie');
const requestPromise = require('request-promise');
const ShopifyToken = require('shopify-token');

const scopes = "write_products";
const forwardingAddress = process.env.HOST;

var shopifyToken = new ShopifyToken({
sharedSecret: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
redirectUri: forwardingAddress + '/shopify/callback',
apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY
})

router.get('/shopify', (req, res) => {
const shop = req.query.shop;
if (!shop) {
    return res.status(400).send('Missing shop parameter. Please add ?shop=your-development-shop.myshopify.com to your request')
}
const shopRegex = /^([\w-]+)\.myshopify\.com/i
const shopName = shopRegex.exec(shop)[1]
const state = shopifyToken.generateNonce();
const url = shopifyToken.generateAuthUrl(shopName, scopes, state);
res.cookie('state', state);
res.redirect(url);
});

router.get('/shopify/callback', (req, res) => {
const { shop, hmac, code, state } = req.query;
const stateCookie = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie).state;

if (state !== stateCookie) {
    // you are unable to set proper state ("nonce") in this case, thus you are getting this error
    return res.status(403).send('Request origin cannot be verified')
}
if (!shop || !hmac || !code) {
    res.status(400).send('Required parameters missing')
}
let hmacVerified = shopifyToken.verifyHmac(req.query)
console.log(`verifying -> ${hmacVerified}`)

// DONE: Validate request is from Shopify
if (!hmacVerified) {
    return res.status(400).send('HMAC validation failed')
}
const accessToken = shopifyToken.getAccessToken(shop, code);
const shopRequestUrl = 'https://' + shop + '/admin/products.json'
const shopRequestHeaders = {
    'X-Shopify-Access-Token': accessToken
}
try {
    const shopResponse = requestPromise.get(shopRequestUrl, { headers: shopRequestHeaders })
    res.status(200).send(shopResponse)
} catch (error) {
    res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.error.error_description)
}

});

module.exports = router;
```